# Равномерное растягивание ширины блоков в зависимости от их наполнения (width 1+width 2+...+width n = 100%; html, css)

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox, выравнивание, width

Всем привет. Передо мной такая задача:
Есть 3 кнопки меню в навбаре. Я хочу распределить их равномерно по ширине экрана (родительского блока), но при этом они (сами элементы li) также должны быть растянуты по ширине так, чтобы занимать собою всё пространство.
Как если бы я им поставил width: 33.33%, только чтобы ширина зависила от наполнения.
Можно ли прописать какую-то логику (может, с использованием js) типа width1_new = width1 / (width1+width2+width3) * 100% ?
Приветствуются и другие решения моей задачи, т.к. всё же хотелось добиться такого результата без javascript'а. Может, можно для li какие-то padding выставить?

```css
ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
/*width: 33%;*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">PROFESSIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">KNOWLEAGE BASE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">PEOPLE</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать дочерним элементам `flex-контейнера` правило `flex-grow:1;`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PROFESSIONS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">KNOWLEAGE BASE</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PEOPLE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная ситуация для flexbox

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:first-child {
  background: pink;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: насчёт верного ответа - кроме flex-grow и width:100% одинакого если ты о этом

Comment: Спасибо большое)